# how to setMessage dialog with EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext, android-alertdialog

I want to create dialog for looping dialog and view edittext into dialog.

1. when activity start, dialog show to looping dialog no.1
2. dialog looping = no.1 input user
3. dialog looping to for show input dialog no.3

My error log :

```
1-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.example.dialog_looping.MainActivity$dialog$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-29 14:54:23.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My full code of app :

```
package com.example.dialog_looping;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new dialog(this));
    }
    public class dialog extends View {

        public dialog(Context context) {
            super(context);


            //this.setNama(name.getText().toString());
            LayoutInflater inflater = (MainActivity.this).getLayoutInflater();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("Input Your Name")
            .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoginputname, null))
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                EditText name;
                name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                //String a = name.setText(name.getText().toString());
                //int z = Integer.valueOf(a);
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                  .setTitle("YOur Name Is")
                  .setMessage(name.getText().toString())
                  .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                  finish();
                  }})
                  .show();
             }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                 finish();
               }
               })
                .show();
                }

        protected CharSequence nama() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
            };


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
.setMessage(name())
```

To

```
.setMessage(name.getText().toString())
```

Comment: hmmmm,,,,,,same error still

this is my full code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZOC5XV9Q2DzRjX6rSU6S1UNsN7Gg5LT-6gBpCRIULNU/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

Improved code for you :

```
    EditText name;
                name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                String a = name.getText().toString();
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("something");
alertDialog.setMessage(name);
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// here you can add functions
}
});
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
```

Try now again.
If my answer was helpful, accept its please.

Comment: hmmmm,,,,,,same error still

this is my full code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZOC5XV9Q2DzRjX6rSU6S1UNsN7Gg5LT-6gBpCRIULNU/edit?pli=1

Comment: thanks to help me,,,
your code error again....

this is my full code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZOC5XV9Q2DzRjX6rSU6S1UNsN7Gg5LT-6gBpCRIULNU/edit?pli=1

this is my error log
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r-DRP55bEXcl9mFfpjlzzwJs38wOwBQ_8pdJ0fAJaKw/edit?pli=1

Comment: I will answer you after 15.

Comment: I know why do you have errror

Comment: why?
please help me, i am newbie,,,, :)

Comment: You have nullpointerexception because your class dialog don't know about edittext  "name". You shold delete dialog class,change setcontentview argument to R.layout.layoutwithedittext and create alertdialog using my method on click the button. Its my dolution. If you have more questions ask please in comments.

Comment: i want to create dialog for looping dialog and view edittext into dialog,,,,you can help me?
1. when activity start, dialog show to looping dialog no.2
2. dialog looping = no.1 input user
3. dialog looping to for show input dialog no.3

please give me sample for my learn....
thanks,,,

Comment: What's time ? I'm from Poland

Comment: 6.50 PM
wow,,,poland,,,,
nice to meet you,,,
do you have account for chat? FB/YM or other?

Comment: 1.10 PM. I will be at Home at 15.00 PM. I haven't Facebook. We can talking using chat on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, but after 3 PM ( my time, your 8 PM )

Comment: here is our chat room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23575/loop-dialog-ty221-room . Go here please. I wait 20 minut

Comment: i can't chat, i don't have reputation,,,,
my reputation is 14.sorry,,,,,

Comment: wait i want to find other chat